# Running a command application through a python 3.xx script on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to interact with a command line program using a python script with subprocess (I think this is what I need to use) and this is what I have to start it.

```
subprocess.run(["C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\xxxxx\\xxxxx.exe"])
```

My goal: To run a command line application that takes a list of urls from a text file or something and pasting them individually into this program which I opened with the above code. When I run the above code, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZASB.jpg)
I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to use the stdin/stdout arguments and that seems like what I need to be looking at.

My intent is to automate this process because I manually copy and paste these links and copy the contents into an excel every day. If I could have this run in batches or something it would make my life easier. I'm just asking how would I get the link from a text file into the command line and copy the resulting output.

Edit: The program that I've been running manually pops up in the CLI, which is why I though subprocess might do the handy work.

Comment: Call `run` with the command-line args list; the input text (i.e. a URL string plus `"\r\n"`) as the `input` option; `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`; and an `encoding` such as "oem", "ansi", or "utf-8". The call returns an object with the output set as the `stdout` attribute.

Comment: @eryksun Doesn't seem to work. Now the program starts up and then disappears. Here's my code:

    `subprocess.run(args=["C:\\Users\\xxx\\xxxx\\xxxxt\\xxxxxx.exe", 
    "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/", "\r\n"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    str.encode("ansi"))`

Comment: I meant something more like this: `p = subprocess.run(["C:\\Users\\xxx\\xxxx\\xxxxt\\xxxxxx.ex‌​e"], input="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/\r\n", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding="ansi");` `print(p.stdout)`.

Comment: @eryksun i ran that and it opened and closed. didn't receive any output. and when i run the script via the CL then I get a syntax error "invalid character in identifier"

Comment: Let's start with a known command and confirm it works for you: `p = subprocess.run(['python.exe', '-c', 'print(input())'], input="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/\r\n", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding="ansi");` `print(p.stdout)`. Please retype the command; don't copy and paste it from here because SO's comments have non-breaking spaces that mess everything up.

Comment: @eryksun I'm getting invalid syntax of the link. But if I use the link copy/paste into the app then it works